# How to find the equation for an ellipse

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, ellipse

I am looking to find the equation for an ellipse given five or six points using the general equation for a conic: 
A x2 + B xy + C y2 + D x + E y + F = 0.

At first I tried using six points. Here is my python code:

```
    import numpy as np
    def conic_section(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6):
        def row(point):
            return [point[0]*point[0], point[0]*point[1], point[1]*point[1],                         
            point[0], point[1], 1]
        matrix=np.matrix([row(p1),row(p2),row(p3),row(p4),row(p5), row(p6)])
        b=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
        return np.linalg.solve(matrix,b)

    print conic_section(np.array([6,5]), np.array([2,9]), np.array([0,0]),         
    np.array([11, 5.5]), np.array([6, 7]), np.array([-1,-1]))
```

The problem is that this will return the solution [0,0,0,0,0,0] because the right hand side of my equation is the zero vector.

I then attempted to change the conic by subtracting the F and dividing it through:

A x2 + B xy + C y2 + D x + E y + F = 0

A x2 + B xy + C y2 + D x + E y = -F

A' x2 + B xy + C' y2 + D' x + E' y = -1.

The reason that this doesn't work though is that if one of my point is (0,0), then I would end up with a Matrix that has a row of zeros, yet the right hand side of the equation would have a -1 for the entries in the vector. In other words, if one of my points is (0,0) - then "F" should be 0, and so I can't divide it out.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean you can't divide it out? Linear algebra is perfectly capable to handle this. Given the six point are *independent*, and are on the ellipse, the system can solve the equation.

Comment: Please provide six points that create trouble.

Comment: If a ellipse has any point touching the origin, the F value in its equation is equal to 0. :) In that case I don't think you can use this method if you have an ellipse without a constant. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If F=0 then you can't divide the equation by F, because you can't divide by zero. Five points which don't work are simply the first five listed: np.array([6,5]), np.array([2,9]), np.array([0,0]),         
    np.array([11, 5.5]), np.array([6, 7]).

Comment: If you know you've got an ellipse (rather than a more general conic section), `A` must be nonzero. Since you can scale `A` through `F` by an arbitrary factory, you could add an extra constraint `A = 1` to your set of linear equations (and if you have six points, then drop one of them; five are enough to determine the conic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have exact points on ellipse, don't need approximation, and use Braikenridge-Maclaurin construction for conic sections by some strange way.

Five points`(x[i],y[i])` determines ellipse with this explicit equation ([mathworld page, eq. 8](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSection.html))

[image]

So to find ellipse equation, you can build [cofactor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Cofactor_expansion_of_the_determinant) of the determinant by minors for the first row. For example, coefficient `A`is determinant value for submatrix from `x1y1` to the right bottom corner, coefficient `B` is negated value of determinant for submatrix without `xiyi` column and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Ellipse equation (without translation and rotation):

[image: \frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b} = 1]

The goal is to resolve this **linear equation** in variable `A` through `F`:

[image: Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0]

Use:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv

# basis parameters of the ellipse
a = 7
b = 4

def ellipse(t, a, b):
    return a*cos(t), b*sin(t)

points = [ellipse(t, a, b) for t in np.linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)]
x, y = [np.array(v) for v in list(zip(*points))]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()

def fit_ellipse(x, y):
    x = x[:, np.newaxis]
    y = y[:, np.newaxis]
    D =  np.column_stack((x**2, x*y, y**2, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    S = np.dot(D.T, D)
    C = np.zeros([6,6])
    C[0, 2] = C[2, 0] = 2
    C[1, 1] = -1
    E, V = eig(np.dot(inv(S), C))
    n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
    return V[:, n]

A, B, C, D, E, F = fit_ellipse(x, y)
K = D**2/(4*A) + E**2/(4*C) - F

# a, b
print('a:', sqrt(K/A), 'b:', sqrt(K/C))
```

Output:

[image: ellipse]

a: 6.999999999999998 b: 4.0

See:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSection.html
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(math%C3%A9matiques)#Forme_matricielle
http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html

Comment: The equations _are_ linear in the unknowns, which are `A` through `F`. The OPs problem is coming from that fact that these are _homogeneous_ linear equations.